# Can't preview Android XML layout - LayoutLib is too recent. Update your tool?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

After upgrading the Android SDK through the AVD manager, I cannot preview XML layouts any longer in eclipse for Android 2.2 previews.  Eclipse says, "LayoutLib is too recent. Update your tool!"

Using the drop-down and choosing any other platform works fine.  Why is this happening for Android 2.2 previews?

I have also updated the ADT plugin for ecplise as well.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17369

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I've read that thread already, and users report that updating to ADT version 12 corrected this issue.  When I check for updates in Eclipse it says I'm all clear and no updates are found.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What version do you currently have? I have version 10.something, and when I check for updates, I find ADT 12 available. You can check your current version by going to Help (or Eclipse on a Mac) -> About Eclipse, then select the Android icon.

Comment: I upgraded from 10.0.1 to 12.0.0 and that's when the issue began.

Answer (score 2):

Updating from 10.0.1 to 12.0.0 resolved this issue for me.

In Eclipse, Help --> Check for updates

You'll likely see three items to be updated to 12.0.0+.  Install, restart Eclipse, and the layout view should display without error.

Comment: ...yes...unfortunately I updated from 10.0.1 to 12.0.0 and I still have the issue.  It's probably something funky with my Eclipse setup.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Same issue here, updated from 10.0.1 to 12.0.0, Help-->Check for updates gives "There is nothing to update."  This is maddening....

Answer (score 1):

More of a fix than an answer, or a fix with no explanation:  r-click on the res\layout*.xml file you want to open, select Open with, then select Android Layout Editor.  That should open the .xml in the graphical layout/design view you're used to.

For whatever reason, after updating from 10.0.1 to 12.0.0, my layout viewer default changed to XML Editor (one of the options under the context menu referenced above), and I have to manually open with different editor.  Opening manually selecting Android Layout Editor seems to set ALE as the default for that .xml file going forward.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my the xml files are already opening in the Android Layout Editor.  I tried changing them to a different one and then changing it back to see if that would solve the issue.  Still there...again....I'm only having problems in Android 2.2...all over views are ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Went in Eclipse->Help->CheckforUpdates.  Selected everything there and hit next.  Keep hitting next until finish.  The update will start at the bottom right hand corner.  Will also ask for permission.  Press "OK".  Will restart eclipse and problem is solved.  I guess there was a bug with ADT but whatever this update fixed it.