# Android beginner Graphical layout not working

Tags: java, android

I get the following error, when i create an android project and go to the `Graphical layout` section in the `main.xml` file. I don't see the black gui screen as [show in this](http://www.learndroidapps.com/images/lesson4-Main_xml.png) image. I get the following warning/error. What should i do to resolve this ?

> The project target (Android 3.0) is still loading. main.xml will
>   refresh automatically once the process is finished.

Comment: Wait until its finished loading. That takes a moment.

Comment: For how long ? i have already waited for 5mins

Comment: Try switching to a different SDK version, 2.2 or 2.3.3 perhaps.  Sometimes in Eclipse, it gets stuck on 3.0 and won't load the GUI for me either.

Comment: Mh ok thats maybe a bit too long. Depending on your machine that may still be possible with honeycomb (eats resources for breakfast usually), but sounds suspicious. Try changing the android version in the top-right corner to something lower (2.2 or 2.3.3) and see if this works.

Comment: when i changed it to 2.2 i get this message `LayoutLib is too recent. Update your tool!`. What does this mean ?

Comment: Not sure, are you on the newest sdk/devtools? If not, maybe try an update as suggested. Open the SDK- and AVD manager and see if there is something under "Available packages". (only the android repo, 3rd partys are not relevant here)

Comment: I found a similar thread that talks about this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083048/cant-preview-android-xml-layout-layoutlib-is-too-recent-update-your-tool

Comment: Solved : Update Eclipse plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update your ADT. For that got to Eclipse -> Check for updates.

That should fix your issue.

Comment: or sometimes just restart the IDE