# LayoutLib is too recent. Update your tool?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Android version 12 and i got error LayoutLib is too recent. Update your tool! How can i solve it. Please help.

Comment: Have you actually tried to update your dev-tools/sdk/adt-plugin?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it is showing as they are already installed

Comment: For your problem check this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17369

Answer (score 12):

[Can't preview Android XML layout - LayoutLib is too recent. Update your tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083048/cant-preview-android-xml-layout-layoutlib-is-too-recent-update-your-tool)

Same question asked here. I had the same issue when I upgraded all the Android SDK components. In Eclipse, I clicked 'Help > Check For Updates' and upgraded everything it prompted. Fixed the issue for me