# Can't See Graphical Layout in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I just update my ADT and when I try to see layout in an old project I get this message

> "LayoutLib is too recent. Update your tool!"

what does it mean? what is LayoutLib?

Comment: this happened to a coworker after the adt update. did you update to version 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to upgrade your ADT Eclipse plugin to the latest version.  You more than likely updated your SDK tools, but didn't update the plugin along with it.  See these links:

[Can't preview Android XML layout - LayoutLib is too recent. Update your tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083048/cant-preview-android-xml-layout-layoutlib-is-too-recent-update-your-tool)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17369

Comment: that seem to be the solution. tnx

Answer (score 0):

If it's still broken after you update, try this:

**Right click** on the layout xml file in the navigator (package explorer) and
choose **open with >** the **"Android Layout Editor"** from the list.

If it's still not working, try some of the other Editors from the list before you choose the Android Layout Editor again. this worked for me;-)

Answer (score -1):

My role as the marketing man was to edit the layouts of the app screens to make them prettier, using the Graphical Layout of Eclipse. As a complete technical dodo, I was working under technical expert direction, but one day when he wasn't looking, I thought I could be clever.... I couldn't.
Like the others on this thread, I couldn't see the graphical layout tab and spent several hours in following the recommendations, updating various SDKs, ADTs etc etc. without remedy.
The solution was simple.
In being 'clever',I had moved the files I wanted to work on, from their position in res/layout to a new folder 'To be edited'. I planned to complete them there and then move them back into res/layout. 
Unfortunately, I didn't realise that Eclipse is expecting to find layout files in res/layout (and why not?).
So I moved one file back into res/layout and bingo! Up came the Graphical Layout tab.
Recommendations:
1. Do not allow marketing people near Eclipse.
2. Provide an upgrade to Eclipse especially for marketing people. When run, a screen appears that says..'Make lunch for the technicians..'